# What material was the stargate made of?

Tags: stargate, composition

In the Movie Stargate, what material was the stargate actually made of? They mentioned the material commonly as 'Mineral'. Has it been mentioned anywhere else in the Stargate Universe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stargates are made of [naqahdah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_in_Stargate#Naqahdah), a fictitious superheavy metal.

Comment: Also, the link says it was not named in the original movie

Answer (score 1):

Stargate was made of naquadah, which is fictional superheavy mineral. Naquadah is superconductive at normal temperature (around 20°C). Although no other materials are mentioned, it is probable that Stargate is made of other materials as well since it would require very elaborate inner workings and systems to operate. This is because Stargate does not simply create stable wormhole, but rather creates very small one and disintegration field that disintegrates objects to fit this thin wormhole. That would be why objects can travel only one direction (particles would collide) and electromagnetic waves can travel both ways. 
In reality, elements with atomic number as high as naquadah would be extremely unstable and theory therefore is, that it must be placed somewhere in the "isle of stability" in the periodic table of elements.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "very thin wormhole" and that being the reason for travel only in one direction?  I don't recall that being in the series at all.

Comment: No. The reason for one-way travel of matter is simply a limitation of the Stargate, not of the wormhole. The dialing gate demolecularizes and the receiving gate reconstructs the travelers.

Comment: It is only logical possibility. Wormholes do not need to disintegrate anything, or be one way or to have blueish event horizon. Wormhole would to the naked eye appear as simple window. You would be able to see through it to the other side, jump there and back without space roller coaster vision. Only logical explanation is, that objects get disintegrated to fit thin wormhole, which is easier to maintain. Thic explanation also covers other aspects and limitations of stargates. I should have mentioned it is not supported by the series but it is explanation widely accepted in the fan community.